# How to Get ID from URL and make it a:focus of the associate id on the page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Click on this link: https://phonestage.wpengine.com/documentation/#admin_guide_2

See, There is a ID(#admin_guide_2) on the last part of the link. I made this work with the page content, So when you load this page, You will see the correct  associate with this ID. 
On the left side this ID also exists on the "Step 1: Authentication". I want this link will focus when someone comes with that link. 
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: hi @mplungjan, Actually scroll on page load is works. My question is about the a:focus on the left sidebar. a:focus is not working after the page load on the left sidebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```js
var hash = "#admin_guide_3" // location.hash

$(function() {
  $("a").filter(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    return href ? href.substring(href.indexOf("#")) === hash : false;
  }).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a name="something">Nothing</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/documentation/#admin_guide_2">Step 1: Authentication</a></li>
  <li><a href="/documentation/#admin_guide_3">Step 2: Configuration &amp; Setup</a></li>
  <li><a href="/documentation/#admin_guide_4">Disconnecting the Telephony Integration or Starting Over &#8211; ADMIN USE ONLY</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your great help. but unfortunately something is happening here.
It shows me a error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined" on console.

Comment: Have a look at the changed script. You have a's without hrefs then

Comment: This is now perfect! Thank you so much  @mplungjan . You are the super hero!